# Reading TDM (Diadem) files from script

Tags: file, matlab, file-conversion

My customer is sending TDM/TDX files captured in National Instruments Diadem, which I haven't got. I'm looking for a way to convert the files into .CSV, XLS or .MAT files for analysis in Matlab (without using Diadem or Diadem DLLs!)

The format consists of a well structured XML file (.TDM) and a binary (.TDX), with the .TDM defining how fields are packed as bits in the binary TDX. I'd like to read the files (for use in Matlab and other environments). Does anyone have a general purpose tool or conversion script in for instance Python or Perl (not using the NI DLL's) or directly in Matlab?

I've looked into buying the tool, but didn't like it for anything other than one-time conversion to a compatible file format.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked your customer to send you the same files in a format that you can more easily read ?  I don't use Diadem but if it's anything like LabView then it will have a number of options for exporting data for other systems, and this might be your best bet.  Failing that, it seems you may have to write your own Matlab to read the binary data, not terribly difficult but tedious and tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a little late, but I have a simple library to read TDM/TDX files in Python.  It works by parsing the TDM file to figure out the data type, then using NumPy.memmap to open the TDX file.  It can then be used like a standard NumPy array.  The code is pretty simple, so you could probably implement something similar in Matlab.

Here's the link: https://bitbucket.org/joshayers/tdm_loader

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little too late, but I think there is a simple way to get the data from TDM files: NI provides plug-ins for reading TDM files into Excel and OpenOffice Calc. Having the data in one of these programs you could use the CSV export. Search google for "tdm excel" or "tdm openoffice".

Hope this helps...
Gemue

Comment: Thanks, this helps to solve my problem. Now I don't need to ask collegues to convert tdm files to csv.........

Comment: I need to convert a pile of these to csv.  Is there a way to do this to hundreds of files without carpal-tunnel by click-death?

Answer (score 0):

The following script can convert all variables into 'variable' struct.

```
    CurrDirectory = '...//';  % Path to current directory
    fileNametdx = '.../utility/';  % Path to TDX file
    %%
    % Data type conversion 
    Dtype.eInt8Usi='int8';
    Dtype.eInt16Usi='int16';
    Dtype.eInt32Usi='int32';
    Dtype.eInt64Usi='int64';
    Dtype.eUInt8Usi='uint8';
    Dtype.eUInt16Usi='uint16';
    Dtype.eUInt32Usi='uint32';
    Dtype.eUInt64Usi='uint64';
    Dtype.eFloat32Usi='single';
    Dtype.eFloat64Usi='double';

    %% Read .tdx file Name
    wb=waitbar(0,'Reading *.tdx Files');
    fileNameTDM = strrep(fileNametdx,'.tdx','.TDM');

    %% Read .TDM
    tdm=xml2struct(fileNameTDM);

    for i=1:numel(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.tdm_channel)

        waitbar((1/numel(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.tdm_channel))*i,wb,['File ' fileNametdx ' conversion started']);
    s1=strsplit(string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.tdm_channel{1, i}.local_columns.Text),'"');
    usi1=s1(2);

    % if condition match untill we get usi2
    for j=1:numel(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.localcolumn)
    usi2=string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.localcolumn{1, j}.Attributes.id);
    if usi1==usi2
        %take new usi
        s2=strsplit(string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.localcolumn{1, j}.values.Text),'"');
        new_usi1=s2(2);


        w1=strsplit(string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.tdm_channel{1, i}.datatype.Text),'_');
        str_1=char(strcat('tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.',lower(w1(2)),'_sequence'));
        str_2=char(strcat('tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.',lower(w1(2)),'_sequence{1, k}.Attributes.id'));
        str_3=char(strcat('tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.',lower(w1(2)),'_sequence{1, k}.values.Attributes.external'));
        str_4=char(strcat('tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.',lower(w1(2)),'_sequence{1, k}.values'));
        for k=1:numel(eval(str_1))
        new_usi2=string(eval(str_2));
         if new_usi1==new_usi2
             if isfield(eval(str_4), 'Attributes')

             inc_value1=string(eval(str_3));

                    for m=1:numel(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block)
                        inc_value2=string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block{1, m}.Attributes.id);
                        if inc_value1==inc_value2

        %                 offset=round(str2num(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block{1, m}.Attributes.byteOffset)/8);
                        length = round(str2num(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block{1, m}.Attributes.length));
                        offset1=round(str2num(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block{1, m}.Attributes.byteOffset));
                        value_type = tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_include.file.block{1, m}.Attributes.valueType;

                        m = memmapfile(fullfile(CurrDirectory,fileNametdx),'Offset',offset1,'Format',{Dtype.(value_type) [length 1] 'dat'},'Writable',true,'Repeat',1);
                        dat=m.Data.dat  ;

                        end
                    end
             else

                 str_5=char(strcat('tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.',lower(w1(2)),'_sequence{1, k}.values.',char(fieldnames(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.string_sequence{1, k}.values))));
                 dat=eval(str_5)';
             end
                    name_variable = string(tdm.usi_colon_tdm.usi_colon_data.tdm_channel{1, i}.name.Text);
                    varname = genvarname(char(name_variable));
                    variable.(varname) = dat;
         end
        end
    end
    end
    end

    waitbar(1,wb,[fileNametdx ' conversion completed']);
    pause(1)
    close(wb)
    delete(fullfile(CurrDirectory,fileNametdx),fullfile(CurrDirectory,fileNameTDM));
    %Output Variable is Struct 
    clearvars -except variable
```

This script requires following XML parser

```
function [ s ] = xml2struct( file )
    %Convert xml file into a MATLAB structure
    % [ s ] = xml2struct( file )
    %
    % A file containing:
    % <XMLname attrib1="Some value">
    %   <Element>Some text</Element>
    %   <DifferentElement attrib2="2">Some more text</Element>
    %   <DifferentElement attrib3="2" attrib4="1">Even more text</DifferentElement>
    % </XMLname>
    %
    % Will produce:
    % s.XMLname.Attributes.attrib1 = "Some value";
    % s.XMLname.Element.Text = "Some text";
    % s.XMLname.DifferentElement{1}.Attributes.attrib2 = "2";
    % s.XMLname.DifferentElement{1}.Text = "Some more text";
    % s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Attributes.attrib3 = "2";
    % s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Attributes.attrib4 = "1";
    % s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Text = "Even more text";
    %
    % Please note that the following characters are substituted
    % '-' by '_dash_', ':' by '_colon_' and '.' by '_dot_'
    %
    % Written by W. Falkena, ASTI, TUDelft, 21-08-2010
    % Attribute parsing speed increased by 40% by A. Wanner, 14-6-2011
    % Added CDATA support by I. Smirnov, 20-3-2012
    %
    % Modified by X. Mo, University of Wisconsin, 12-5-2012

        if (nargin < 1)
            clc;
            help xml2struct
            return
        end

        if isa(file, 'org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl') || isa(file, 'org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl')
            % input is a java xml object
            xDoc = file;
        else
            %check for existance
            if (exist(file,'file') == 0)
                %Perhaps the xml extension was omitted from the file name. Add the
                %extension and try again.
                if (isempty(strfind(file,'.xml')))
                    file = [file '.xml'];
                end

                if (exist(file,'file') == 0)
                    error(['The file ' file ' could not be found']);
                end
            end
            %read the xml file
            xDoc = xmlread(file);
        end

        %parse xDoc into a MATLAB structure
        s = parseChildNodes(xDoc);

    end

    % ----- Subfunction parseChildNodes -----
    function [children,ptext,textflag] = parseChildNodes(theNode)
        % Recurse over node children.
        children = struct;
        ptext = struct; textflag = 'Text';
        if hasChildNodes(theNode)
            childNodes = getChildNodes(theNode);
            numChildNodes = getLength(childNodes);

            for count = 1:numChildNodes
                theChild = item(childNodes,count-1);
                [text,name,attr,childs,textflag] = getNodeData(theChild);

                if (~strcmp(name,'#text') && ~strcmp(name,'#comment') && ~strcmp(name,'#cdata_dash_section'))
                    %XML allows the same elements to be defined multiple times,
                    %put each in a different cell
                    if (isfield(children,name))
                        if (~iscell(children.(name)))
                            %put existsing element into cell format
                            children.(name) = {children.(name)};
                        end
                        index = length(children.(name))+1;
                        %add new element
                        children.(name){index} = childs;
                        if(~isempty(fieldnames(text)))
                            children.(name){index} = text; 
                        end
                        if(~isempty(attr)) 
                            children.(name){index}.('Attributes') = attr; 
                        end
                    else
                        %add previously unknown (new) element to the structure
                        children.(name) = childs;
                        if(~isempty(text) && ~isempty(fieldnames(text)))
                            children.(name) = text; 
                        end
                        if(~isempty(attr)) 
                            children.(name).('Attributes') = attr; 
                        end
                    end
                else
                    ptextflag = 'Text';
                    if (strcmp(name, '#cdata_dash_section'))
                        ptextflag = 'CDATA';
                    elseif (strcmp(name, '#comment'))
                        ptextflag = 'Comment';
                    end

                    %this is the text in an element (i.e., the parentNode) 
                    if (~isempty(regexprep(text.(textflag),'[\s]*','')))
                        if (~isfield(ptext,ptextflag) || isempty(ptext.(ptextflag)))
                            ptext.(ptextflag) = text.(textflag);
                        else
                            %what to do when element data is as follows:
                            %<element>Text <!--Comment--> More text</element>

                            %put the text in different cells:
                            % if (~iscell(ptext)) ptext = {ptext}; end
                            % ptext{length(ptext)+1} = text;

                            %just append the text
                            ptext.(ptextflag) = [ptext.(ptextflag) text.(textflag)];
                        end
                    end
                end

            end
        end
    end

    % ----- Subfunction getNodeData -----
    function [text,name,attr,childs,textflag] = getNodeData(theNode)
        % Create structure of node info.

        %make sure name is allowed as structure name
        name = toCharArray(getNodeName(theNode))';
        name = strrep(name, '-', '_dash_');
        name = strrep(name, ':', '_colon_');
        name = strrep(name, '.', '_dot_');

        attr = parseAttributes(theNode);
        if (isempty(fieldnames(attr))) 
            attr = []; 
        end

        %parse child nodes
        [childs,text,textflag] = parseChildNodes(theNode);

        if (isempty(fieldnames(childs)) && isempty(fieldnames(text)))
            %get the data of any childless nodes
            % faster than if any(strcmp(methods(theNode), 'getData'))
            % no need to try-catch (?)
            % faster than text = char(getData(theNode));
            text.(textflag) = toCharArray(getTextContent(theNode))';
        end

    end

    % ----- Subfunction parseAttributes -----
    function attributes = parseAttributes(theNode)
        % Create attributes structure.

        attributes = struct;
        if hasAttributes(theNode)
           theAttributes = getAttributes(theNode);
           numAttributes = getLength(theAttributes);

           for count = 1:numAttributes
                %attrib = item(theAttributes,count-1);
                %attr_name = regexprep(char(getName(attrib)),'[-:.]','_');
                %attributes.(attr_name) = char(getValue(attrib));

                %Suggestion of Adrian Wanner
                str = toCharArray(toString(item(theAttributes,count-1)))';
                k = strfind(str,'='); 
                attr_name = str(1:(k(1)-1));
                attr_name = strrep(attr_name, '-', '_dash_');
                attr_name = strrep(attr_name, ':', '_colon_');
                attr_name = strrep(attr_name, '.', '_dot_');
                attributes.(attr_name) = str((k(1)+2):(end-1));
           end
        end
    end
```